# Weird cypher behaviour; bug?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using neo4j-2.0.0 M3 and running a rather simple query. But the results I'm getting make no sense to me. This is my data model for the query:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/edzKR.jpg

The top items are "suppliers" and the bottom ones "factories".

The query

```
START s=node:__types__(className='Supplier'),f=node:__types__(className='Factory')
MATCH (s)-[d:delivers]->(f) 
RETURN s.name,d.price, f.name;
```

only returns 5 rows(wrong, there should be nine items):

```
5 rows
s.name      d.price f.name
"Amazon"    30      "Köln"
"eBay"      33      "Köln"
"Amazon"    29      "Frankfurt"
"Amazon"    32      "Mannheim"
"Conrad"    27      "Stuttgart"
```

now oddly enough if I run the same query but dont bind the relationship to a varibale, I get 7 rows

```
START s=node:__types__(className='Supplier'),f=node:__types__(className='Factory')
MATCH (s)-[delivers]->(f) 
RETURN s.name, f.name;

7 rows
s.name      f.name
"Amazon"    "Köln"
"eBay"      "Köln"
"eBay"      "Frankfurt"
"Amazon"    "Frankfurt"
"eBay"      "Mannheim"
"Amazon"    "Mannheim"
"Conrad"    "Stuttgart"
```

The only way I found to get the correct amount of rows, is by not using the start clause.
Whats going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you may be missing some entries in your index. Can you try doing just the start/return clause without any match?

Comment: Great idea Wes. Without the match I get 12 rows, which seems right(the cartesian product as I learned from one of your articels :) )

Comment: Can you try just one index at a time to make sure it's exactly what you're expecting for each index query. Can you get it to reproduce in the console? If so, probably time to create a github issue, or add to the existing one. We've got one already for match not returning all the results it should with start node sets. https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/897

Comment: `START s=node:__types__(className='Supplier')
RETURN s.name;
Returned 3 rows.Query took 41ms
s.name
"Amazon"
"eBay"
"Conrad"

START f=node:__types__(className='Factory')
RETURN f.name;
f.name
"Köln"
"Frankfurt"
"Mannheim"
"Stuttgart"
`
The indexes seem to be working I guess.

Comment: Yep. :( Sounds like it might be a similar issue.

Comment: I`ll file a new issue then. Especially since the behaviour when binding the relationship to a variable is odd. Do you have a recommendation on which version I should use till then, 1.9 or 2.0.0 M2? Thank you for you help.

Comment: M02 probably has the same issue, although it seems really intermittent. If you're ok without using labels just use 1.9 for now. If you need labels, avoid using START.